# How to load AddThis only once in a plone collection with "all content"-view?

Tags: collections, plone, addthis, plone-4.x

When I create a collection in Plone and set the display view to "All content", my AddThis icons are loaded multiple times.

By default I have some social icons within the header of every page, they come from the addon "AddThis". When loading n items in a collection with the given view, it seems that my social icons are loaded n times, one besides the other. Other display views work fine.

Is there a workaround for this or someone has an idea how to avoid this behaviour?

I'm using Plone 4.3.1 with collective.addthis 1.3.3

Comment: `collective.addthis` adds a viewlet to the `plone.belowcontentbody` viewletManager. The "all content" view renders this viewlet once per item in the result. I guess you have to custimize this view, or write one, which does not renders the `plone.belowcontentbody` manager. Or you can chose a different default view for the collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the following workaround will help you:

**configure.zcml:**

```
<browser:viewlet
    name="collective.addthis"
    class="collective.addthis.addthis.AddThisViewlet"
    manager="plone.app.layout.viewlets.interfaces.IBelowContent"
    permission="zope.Public"
    layer="collective.addthis.interfaces.IAddThisBrowserLayer"
/>
```

**viewlets.xml:**

```
<order manager="plone.belowcontent" skinname="YOURLAYERSKINNAME">
    ...
    <viewlet name="collective.addthis" />
    ...
</order>
<hidden manager="plone.belowcontentbody" skinname="YOURLAYERSKINNAME">
    ...
    <viewlet name="collective.addthis" />
    ...
</hidden>
```